# XML - XSLT Transformation

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

Trying some for a while but ain't know what to do no more. Can somebody tell me whats wrong why my code? I want like a little table
within these information. 'preciate every form of help of yo guys
awsedtrtfgzuhjikoplpäköjoilhgukfzdtfzgukhilöjokäpl#üäöjolhigkujfzhtgukhiljokpkäöjohilgukfzdtsretrdztfuzgiuhiljköl

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="">
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TEST</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <h2>Person-Information</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>@person</th>
      <th>@eyecolor</th>
      <th>@job</th>
      <th>@year</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select=""/>@person</td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select=""/>@eyecolor</td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select=""/>@jobs</td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select=""/>@year</td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="cdcatalog.xls" version="2.0"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <person>Bob Dylan</person>
    <eyecolor>brown</eyecolor>
    <job>Teacher</job>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>Bonnie Tyler</person>
    <eyecolor>blue</eyecolor>
    <job>Author</job>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>Dolly Parton</person>
    <eyecolor>brown</eyecolor>
    <job>Accountant</job>
    <year>1982</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>Gary Moore</person>
    <eyecolor>blue</eyecolor>
    <job>Virgin records</job>
    <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>Eros Ramazzotti</person>
    <eyecolor>green</eyecolor>
    <job>Chef</job>
    <year>1997</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>Bee Gees</person>
    <eyecolor>blue</eyecolor>
    <job>Magican</job>
    <year>1998</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>Dr.Hook</person>
    <eyecolor>blue</eyecolor>
    <job>Doctor</job>
    <year>1973</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>Rod Stewart</person>
    <eyecolor>blue</eyecolor>
    <job>Atlethe</job>
    <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>Andrea Bocelli</person>
    <eyecolor>green</eyecolor>
    <job>Pilot</job>
    <year>1996</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>Percy Sledge</person>
    <eyecolor>brown</eyecolor>
    <job>Captain</job>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>Savage Rose</person>
    <eyecolor>green</eyecolor>
    <job>Army</job>
    <year>1995</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>Kenny Rogers</person>
    <eyecolor>blue</eyecolor>
    <job>Music Master</job>
    <year>1995</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>Will Smith</person>
    <eyecolor>brown</eyecolor>
    <job>Actor</job>
    <year>1971</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>Van Morrison</person>
    <eyecolor>blue</eyecolor>
    <job>Developer</job>
    <year>1971</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>Jorn Hoel</person>
    <eyecolor>green</eyecolor>
    <job>Tutor</job>
    <year>1996</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>Cat Stevens</person>
    <eyecolor>blue</eyecolor>
    <job>Painter</job>
    <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>Sam Brown</person>
    <eyecolor>blue</eyecolor>
    <job>Chef</job>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>T`Pau</person>
    <eyecolor>blue</eyecolor>
    <job>Graphicdesigner</job>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>Tina Turner</person>
    <eyecolor>blue</eyecolor>
    <job>Teacher</job>
    <year>1983</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>Kim Larsen</person>
    <eyecolor>green</eyecolor>
    <job>Accountant</job>
    <year>1983</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>Luciano Pavarotti</person>
    <eyecolor>blue</eyecolor>
    <job>Consultant</job>
    <year>1991</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>Otis Redding</person>
    <eyecolor>brown</eyecolor>
    <job>Mechanic</job>
    <year>1968</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <person>Mike Dean</person>
    <eyecolor>green</eyecolor>
    <job>Engineer</job>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

ng with my codes?

Comment: Could you please add your current output and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
  <td><xsl:value-of select=""/>@person</td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select=""/>@eyecolor</td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select=""/>@jobs</td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select=""/>@year</td>
```

do:

```
  <td><xsl:value-of select="person"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="eyecolor"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="job"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
```

Comment: Thanks 4 the advice, but this didn't work either :((

Comment: "Didn't work" is not a useful description of a problem. You can see the adjusted code working here:  https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93PXKqb (click the HTML button in the result pane to see the rendered result).